# Does Windows 7 Home Premium remember network share passwords?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, security

One of the most annoying limitations of both Windows XP Home and Vista Home Premium was they did not remember network passwords after reboot. Vista even had a 'remember password' check box which did nothing.

Does Windows 7 Home Premium remember network passwords?

Edited to add: I am talking here about network shared resources, like \\server\music or something, not wireless access passwords.

Also Edited to add: I have now tried this on the final release, and passwords can be remembered, although sometimes this requires manually setting of username/password in the 'Credential Manager' in User Settings in Control Panel.

Comment: You can check it with an old good [Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html) utility.
So I've checked my RDS passwords ;)

Comment: AFAICT, this is not the expected behaviour of any of the above OSes. They all *should* remember passwords and do for some people, but not for everyone (Windows 7 is broken for me as I type this). You mention that "google suggests it is ... the expected behaviour" in a comment below. Can you post a link which says that, because I can't find any.

Comment: @rjmunro I don't think you are right - Chris's info re Vista Home is correct in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question as I went and did it to find out. I installed Home Premium in a Virtual Box VM. Went to a password protected share \server\blah, ticked the box to remember password and then shutdown. Restarted VM and it appears that the password was indeed remembered.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your issue is because both of these versions of Windows remembered passwords for me.  I have a laptop with Vista Home Premium right here that remembers the password just fine.  I am assuming this is a wireless issue you are experiencing and suspect you have a network issue in that your computer is constantly searching for the best connection.  Are you experiencing this on one computer you used for both OS's or is it different computers?  Does your computer remember the correct time?

Comment: Are you talking about remembering the password between boots? Certainly never did for me, unless there has been a recent update. Will have to check on one Home Premium machine.

Comment: Yes, I only put in the password once and it is always there.  And I've done this on all my machines and never had to input it again.

Comment: Nothing to do with wireless this is a wired network, I can definitely repeat it, and google suggests it is very common, and the expected behaviour.

Comment: I was able to remember passwords between boots on Windows XP Pro, but not with Vista Ultimate.  Works for me with Windows 7 Home Premium.  I expected I had some setting incorrect on Vista and never did bother to figure out what.